# how to use AsyncFileUpload to read a file content in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asyncfileupload

i have a AsyncFileUpload control :

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="venfileupld" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="ProcessUpload" />
```

on its `OnUploadedComplete` event i am writing this code :

```
protected void ProcessUpload(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string name = venfileupld.FileName.ToString();
    string filepath = "upload_excel/" + name;
    venfileupld.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(name));

}
```

now i have to read the content of the uploaded file ... i have a function for that:

```
public void writetodb(string filename)
{
    string[] str;
    string vcode = "";
    string pswd = "";
    string vname = "";
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
    string line="";

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        str = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        vcode = str[0];
        pswd = str[1];
        vname = str[2];
        insertdataintosql(vcode, pswd, vname);
    }
    lblmsg4.Text = "Data Inserted Sucessfully";
}
```

now my query is that how i can get the uploaded file to pass to this function ?

**UPDATE**

i have done this :

```
protected void ProcessUpload(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string name = venfileupld.FileName.ToString();
    string filepath = "upload_excel/" + name;
    venfileupld.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(name));
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
    writetodb(filepath);

}
```

but getting an error... file not found

Comment: What's the problem, why can't you simply call that method from `ProcessUpload`?

Comment: You access the file that is now on the server itself.  You know where the document is because of `filepath` in your very own code.

Comment: i called that but i am getting error .. file not found

Comment: Yes, because you're saving it as `Server.MapPath(name)` but you are passing `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.FileName)` to the method. Have you tried my code below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i have understood the problem, but isn't it easy as:

```
protected void ProcessUpload(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.filename);
    string dir = Server.MapPath("upload_excel/");
    string path = Path.Combine(dir, name);
    venfileupld.SaveAs(path);
    writetodb(path);
}
```

`SaveAs` will save the file on the server, so you can do what you want with it afterwards.

Comment: i am getting an error `The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path 'upload_excel/VENDOR.csv' is not rooted.` on line `venfileupld.SaveAs(path);`

Comment: @ArindamDas: Edited my answer. The directory is `Server.MapPath("upload_excel/")` and the name is `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.filename)`.

Comment: hello sir that solution u gave worked fine in my localhost but when i am doing this in a hosting server i am getting error.. the file is getting uploaded in the server but i think i am not getting the file for the function `writetodb()` can u 1sec help me on this ?\